# To send HTTP GET request with body in Xcode Obj C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, http, get

I am developing an application in which I need to send HTTP GET request with a custom body content as like POST request.
When I just change the HTTP method to GET from POST , I am getting the following error.

```
nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [9 server.url ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 4294967295 frame count, 0 byte count
tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
```

Forming the request as follows,

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest 
requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:domainName] 
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
 NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestData options:0 error:nil];
[urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

In the server I am getting the following error message for GET request,

```
Error: request aborted
at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:269:10)
at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:280:11)
at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:293:5)
at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
at TCP._onclose (net.js:475:12)
```

Please correct me if I am doing any mistake in sending the request.

Comment: I think it's API side issue..

Comment: test ur url in rest client check whether u r getting response 200 or not

Comment: What happens if you set the `content-length` header manually?

Comment: @JeremyP Getting the same errors when `content-length` was set.

Comment: I have found the issue that it will encounter error while sending the body in GET request to REST API. I have tried to send the request using some REST clients which doesn't accept the body text for GET method.

Comment: Can you include the contents of `domainName` and `requestData`?  The problem is likely buried in one of those entities.

Comment: You are not supposed to send request body in HTTP GET. That's what POST, PATCH and PUT are for. If you need to, you can serialize any payload in GET parameters, but keep in mind URLs have length limit.